# Ext Panel not resizing on accordian expand

Tags: javascript, extjs, accordion

I have a panel with an accordian layout containing multiple (max. 10) property grids.

This works fine when there are a couple of property grid items and there is space in the panel to expand them. However if the panel is full of collapsed grids then they cannot be expanded. Manually increasing the height of the panel allows them to be expanded.

autoScroll is enabled. If I set autoHeight true the panel sizes to fit all items collapsed but wont resize to expand one.

Hopefully someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

I am working with Ext 3.4.0 due to compatibility with GeoExt.

Thanks

Tom

Example showing 2 property grids expanding correctly 
http://s9.postimg.org/ex4e6nxwv/working.jpg)
Example showing 10 property grids that wont expand
http://s13.postimg.org/r06ylu2h3/not.jpg

Code for creating panel and propertygrids:

```
items.push({
  xtype: "propertygrid",
  title: title,
  source: feature.attributes,
  sorting: false
});

if (items.length > 0) {
  new GeoExt.Popup({
    title: "Feature Info - (" + items.length + " Results)" + maxFeatures,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    layout: "accordion",
    autoScroll: true,
    map: Map,
    location: evt.xy,
    items: items
  }).show();
}
```

Comment: Could you please reproduce the problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) save and post the link?

Comment: Here it is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SFMpd/1/) thanks for looking

Comment: Thanks. Makes helping much easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to get it to do what you want as it is without eliminating the height parameter alltogether which will obviously mean it will be taller.

If you want to keep it at that height, you can just throw it inside another panel:

```
var expandos = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 300,
    title: 'Accordion with ' + grids.length + ' panels',
    layout: 'accordion',
    resizable: true,
    items: grids
});

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: 'center_div',
    height:400,
    width:315,
    autoScroll: true,
    items:expandos
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SFMpd/2/

Comment: Thanks for that, that's exactly what I was looking for. Is there a reason the first property grid is stuck open all the time though?

Comment: No problem. [Please accept the answer if it's correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). The first property grid is open because it's in an [accordion](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Accordion) panel -- they always have one open -- that's just how they work. [There are some hacks out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=extjs+accordion+layout+collapse+all), but it's not built-in.

Comment: For me the first grid is staying open even when another is expanded. All other grids act as normal (only one open at a time) but the first one is always open as well. [image](http://postimg.org/image/4rup7wjbl/46466e97/) Thanks again

Comment: Ah. Looks like the `resizable:true` was causing that. Take that out and see if that helps. http://jsfiddle.net/SFMpd/3/ If you need it to be resizable, you can add it to the outer panel. http://jsfiddle.net/SFMpd/4/

Comment: Hmm I still get it even with the last 2 fiddles you linked. Weirdly if I create a dummy first grid outside the loop with a height of 0 the grid shows up with no panels expanded and the dummy one hidden but as soon as you one the dummy also expands [http://jsfiddle.net/LLwz9/](http://jsfiddle.net/LLwz9/)

Comment: I will be able to try with the real code I'm trying to get working tomorrow morning, hopefully this bug is just down to something I did in the fiddle!

Comment: The two I linked have the first open for me, but it closes. LLwz9 is acting weird because the thing is there, but empty. Hiding it seems to work fine and gets what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/LLwz9/4

Comment: Doh. Unfortunately your fix doesn't seem to work in my real code. Stupidly the fiddle I created was in ext 4.2 instead of 3.4. Using 3.4 wrapping in the extra panel doesn't seem to help. [jsfiddle.net/LLwz9/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/LLwz9/5/) So close and yet so far! (I couldn't find an online css for 3.4 to link to so the fiddle doesn't look right)

Comment: Oh man, sorry about that.. You did mention it in your question... It seems like the accordion was released in 3.4 and it appears to be super buggy. Maybe there are browser issues... Even the example in the docs doesn't run correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/LLwz9/6/ Not sure where to go from here. Perhaps there is something besides accordion which would work?

Comment: Yea back to the drawing board to do use something else I think. Thanks for all your help though.